# Generating SMART errors to make sure I'm detecting them correctly

Tags: smart

I wrote a script that checks various server's HDDs for SMART errors and takes some action if it finds any.

Non of our servers are reporting any SMART errors and instead of waiting to see if my script picks them up when disks start failing I'd like to be definitively sure it is working correctly.

Is there some utility that can generate "fake" smart errors so I can see my script in action? I'm about to bang an old HDD on my desk to see if I get it almost broken enough to throw errors, but I don't think that's gonna work.

Also, this is not a question about my script, I'm just wondering if I can generate SMART errors to test detection of them (which would be useful for any server monitoring software).

Comment: Banging the hard drive may be a satisfying activity, but isn't likely to give you confidence in your script. You'll want to write or find a utility that will emulate a SCSI device and generate arbitrary messages on the bus. Since you haven't said anything about your development or deployment environments, I can't make any suggestions.